# How do I migrate:refresh a specific table in my database?

Tags: laravel, refresh, migrate

I want to migrate:refresh a specific table called scores. I tried this:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/scores
```

but it says nothing to migrate.

Comment: As I see `--path` used only for create migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refresh a *single* migration if its not the **last one**, but you can `step` back in the migrations chain.

Assuming that you have five migrations and your table is at fourth place you can do like this:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --step=2
```

With this command you refresh the last two migrations.

Note that each migration file name contains a timestamp which allows Laravel to determine the order of the migrations.

You can use the `--path` argument but it should be a directory in wich the command searches for migrations not a single migration file.

If you run:

```
php artisan help migrate:refresh
```

You can see all the parameters accepted.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do this by using  Specify the path to the migrations.

**Follow these steps:**

first of all to create a migration, use the `make:migration` command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_scores1_table
php artisan make:migration create_scores2_table
php artisan make:migration create_scores3_table
```

The new migration will be placed in your **database/migrations** directory. Each migration file name contains a timestamp like this:

```
2019_09_04_045427_create_scores1_table.php 
2019_09_04_045500_create_scores2_table.php 
2019_09_04_045518_create_scores3_table.php
```

Now, you want to `refresh` a specific table(*for example:* **scores2 table**), so you can be used like this:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/2019_09_04_045500_create_scores2_table.php
```

It only refresh the **scores2** table and not all the rest of the table

Comment: OP has issues with `migrate:refresh`?

Comment: Yes @vivek_23  I have updated my answer, check and let me know it's correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can migrate:refresh selected migrations. You left off the .php extension from your line of code.

It should look like this example

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/2020_09_28_224702_create_addresses_table.php
```

So, if scores is your migration file name, add .php

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/scores
```